# Execution error of multiple C files in Petalinux

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux, bitbake, petalinux

i am new with Xilinx Petalinux SDK 2016.4. I had successfully a linux operating system on the target Zybo-Z7 board. I built also a helloworld application and it's fine until now. Currently i want to test my application , which has the name `test.c`, with extra one header and C-file (`new.c`, `new.h`).
The files test.c, new.c, new.h are located in the path:

/$Petalinux-project-dir/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-apps/test/test

test.c has the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "new.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("Hello World!\n");

        return 0;
}
```

new.c has the following code:

```
#include "new.h"

void fun(void)
{
    printf("my function!\n");

}
```

new.h has the following single line code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Makefile has the following content:

```
APP = test

# Add any other object files to this list below
APP_OBJS = test.o
APP_OBJS += new.o


all: build

build: $(APP)

$(APP): $(APP_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(APP_OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(APP) $(OBJS)
```

finally, bitbake file test.bb:

```
#
# This file is the test recipe.
#

SUMMARY = "Simple test application"
SECTION = "PETALINUX/apps"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://test.c \
           file://new.c \
           file://new.h \
           file://Makefile \
          "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
         oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 test ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 new ${D}${bindir}
}
```

then i tried to build the application by typing the command:

```
petalinux-build -c test -x build
```

but i am getting the following error message in the log.do_configure :

```
DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
NOTE: make clean
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.

petalinux-build -c test -x build 
ERROR: oe_runmake failed


ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /$petalinux-project-directory/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/test/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.7230)
```

i had the following in console:

```
    petalinux-build -c test -x build
    [INFO] building test
    [INFO] sourcing bitbake
    INFO: bitbake test -c build
    Loading cache: 100% |###########################################| ETA:  00:00:00
    Loaded 2942 entries from dependency cache.
    Parsing recipes: 100% |#########################################| Time: 00:00:02
    Parsing of 2326 .bb files complete (2292 cached, 34 parsed). 2941 targets, 196 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
    NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
    NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
    NOTE: Checking sstate mirror object availability (for 38 objects)
    NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
    NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
    ERROR: test-1.0-r0 do_configure: oe_runmake failed
    ERROR: test-1.0-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /$Petalinux-project-dir/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/test/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.7230)
    ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /$Petalinux-project-dir/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/test/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.7230
    Log data follows:
    | DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
    | DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
    | DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
    | NOTE: make clean
    | make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
    | ERROR: oe_runmake failed
    | ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /$Petalinux-project-dir/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-xilinx-linux-gnueabi/test/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.7230)
    ERROR: Task 5 (/$Petalinux-project-dir/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-apps/test/test.bb, do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
    NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 610 tasks of which 605 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
    Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:

    Summary: 1 task failed:
      /$Petalinux-project-dir/project-spec/meta-user/recipes-apps/test/test.bb, do_configure
    Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
    ERROR: Failed to build test
```

I tried:
 https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/How-to-build-when-multiple-source-files-in-rootfs-of-petalinux/td-p/780949
and 
https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/67189.html
and also this similar problem
[How to build when multiple source files in rootfs in embedded linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290753/how-to-build-when-multiple-source-files-in-rootfs-in-embedded-linux)
but it doesn't work!

can you please help me?

Comment: I made another try with changing the makefile as follows: 
APP = test ..... but also the app test.c gives nothing on the target. new.c is not seen on the target

# Add any other object files to this list below
APP_OBJS = test.o
APP_OBJS += new.o


.PHONY: all build clean

all: build

build: $(APP)

$(APP): $(APP_OBJS)
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(APP_OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
 $(RM) $(APP) $(OBJS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `clean` target in your makefile. Try:

```
APP := test

APP_OBJS := test.o new.o

.PHONY: all build clean

all: build

build: $(APP)

$(APP): $(APP_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(APP_OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(APP) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try your answer now and give you my feedback

Comment: @A.SWelcome to Stackoverflow! It's one question at a time here. If the solution of the
problem you (originally) posted reveals a new problem, and you can't solve it yourself, you should post a new question.
You should *not* change your question to another one by rolling in helpful answers, rendering them irrelevant.
See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @A.S You may [rollback to revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52517180/revisions) if you wish.

Comment: Sorry for changing the original post. Now the original post is back. well i tried your suggestion. The good news that the error is gone a way. But when i load the linux operating system on the target Zybo board, the application test.c is giving nothing when i try to implement it. Also the application new.c is not loaded in the linux image. I also deleted the third line form do_install "install -m 0755 new ${D}${bindir}" because that the application new.c is loaded in the same path of the application test.c

Comment: @A.S Thank you for reverting the post :) To stand any chance of getting help with the new problem you should post another question, carefully presenting the information readers can use to investigate it.